# Can anyone identify this church?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, religion

This is a picture of a church in northern Germany. It was taken in northern Germany enroute from Kaiserslautern to Denmark.
Can anyone tell me where it is and what denomination it is?  I was told by someone in my facebook group that this might be the Catholic Church in Rockenhausen.  I checked it on Google Maps and it looks similar...

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2177969588886856&set=gm.10156575688223993&type=3&ifg=1

[image: Tower and what looks might be a church building behind it.]

Fabulous!  Thank you Nuesser!  A person on my facebook group mentioned that she thought it was the church in Rockenhausen and I tried to prove it, but couldn't get the right view angle.  Yours is perfect and the answer is definitive.

Comment: How sure are you that it's a church? For all one can tell from the photo it might be a water tower ... The yellow building _behind_ the tower could be a church but looks to me like it's separate from it.

Comment: To me it looks like a building build as a church but no indication it is still used as a church.

Comment: Henning Makholm.  If you look at the right side of the tower, you will see where the tower and 'the yellow building behind it' are part of the same building.  I do not know if this a church, I made an assumption and asked the question, that's all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think we can help you. The quality of the photograph is absolutely lousy, I cannot even decipher the street sign. Germany has a zillion towers, we have *Kirchtürme, Wassertürme, Pulvertürme, Bismarcktürme, Taubentürme, Schuldtürme* and so on and on and on. Without at least an approximate location it's senseless.

Comment: Thorsten S.  Thanks. It was taken in northern Germany enroute from Kaiserslautern to Denmark.  But, thanks for looking at anyway.

Comment: @FlemingIsle it seems possible that the yellow structures were added to the original bulding. On the left and right, the yellow structures are in front. On the left, the yellow's red roof might be a little behind, but on the right, the black tower is definitely behind the main tower. An interesting picture.

Comment: @flemingIsle if you (or someone you know) took the picture, chances are it contains geolocation information (if it was taken with a phone that’s highly probable, with a digital camera it’s less likely).

Comment: @FlemingIsle 1. You should edit your question to incorporate the information about the route from  Kaiserslautern to Denmark. It's too important to get buried in the comments. 2. Do you have access to a higher resolution picture and can decipher the sign in front?

Comment: @FlemingIsle Google Images has a *Search by image* feature. You upload an image, and then enter a search term, and google will find images which are **visually similar** to the image. You might have some success looking on there.

Comment: @Sam I tried that with no luck.

Comment: @FlemingIsle Kaiserslautern and Rockehausen is not even remotely [Northern Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Germany). It was pure luck that the church was found in an answer.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like [Katholische Pfarrkirche St.Sebastian](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Sebastian_(Rockenhausen)) in Rockenhausen.

[image: Photo from Wikipedia]

*(photo from Wikipedia)*

The [view from the Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pfarrei+Hl.+Franz+von+Assisi+Rockenhausen/@49.6308986,7.8209397,464m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47961ae00fefa36d:0xd4e08bc0959fdcf2!8m2!3d49.6308687!4d7.8227006):
[image]

You can see the white building which is on the left side behind the churche on your photo.

Comment: Incredible detective work. I was kinda guessing that it's not exactly in northern Germany as the steepness of the hill (on the original photo) next to the church would be highly uncommon for northern Germany. But Rockehausen is - according to Google Maps - even in the southern half of the country, quite next to Kaiserslautern. So great job in finding it anyway.

Comment: Clearly correct (though, @DCTLib, before we're too impressed with Neusser's incredible sleuthing skills, note that the OP edited the solution into the question _before_ this answer was posted).